# Unlock multiple android devices through adb

Tags: android, macos, bash, shell, adb

I have been successfully using `adb shell input keyevent 26` to unlock an android phone over adb.

However, when I connect multiple devices to my mac this is reutrned:

> error: more than one device/emulator

Is there a way to unlock multiple android devices at once through a shell script?

Thanks,

Liam

Answer (score 1):

You are able to unlock multiple devices (or use shell whatsover by defining their serial number (given by adb devices).

Please check on the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html#shellcommands) for the syntax of the command

`adb [-d|-e|-s <serialNumber>] shell <shell_command>`